# Load bootstrap badges to a column of bootstrap table when dynamic database content loads to bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table with the fields order_no, order_status and action. I have used ajax to load the 'order' data from the database dynamically to that table. For every records, two buttons 'edit/detete' are also added. Data load function with the two buttons works fine. However, when data loads to table, I don't want to display the status as normal text within the table column, instead I want status to display on a bootstrap badge for every records. Please, show me how to do that. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Because of the data fetching process works fine, I will only show the function uses by ajax to load the bootstrap table.

js:

```
function loadOrderData(data){

        $(function() {
            $('#orderTable').bootstrapTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [ {},{},  
                {
                  field: 'operate',
                  title: 'Action',
                  align: 'center',
                  valign: 'middle',
                  clickToSelect: false,
                  formatter : function(value,row,index) {
                    return '<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-up\' pageID="'+row.id+'"></button> <button class=\'btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn-del\' pageID="'+row.id+'"></button>';
                  }
                }
              ],              
          });
      });
 }
```

I searched and searched for a solution, but nothing I could find. Only one post I found that might answer my question in this link :[Using Bootstrap Labels in Bootstrap tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971703/using-bootstrap-labels-in-bootstrap-tables)

The link which leads to answer also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify where is the *status* you are referring to? ("...I don't want to display the status as normal text...")

Comment: when an order is placed the order_status column gets the value 1. When order is processing the value updated into 2. so, according to the value I can display an order status as processing or waiting (as a text value). What I need is, display processing or waiting on a bootstrap badge.

Comment: So in your bootstrapTable you define 3 columns - the second one being `order_status` (not shown in your code), right? Then i guess you can use a `formatter` function on that column as well - to convert the text value, into a badge.

Comment: @verjas ,I am so grateful for you for making my mind open. I grabbed the column value and put it on a badge using formatter function same as you said. Thank You.